# Interpolate array (x,y,z,V)

Tags: interpolation

I would like to interpolate a numeric matrix that corresponds to a scalar field in a 3D geometry.

Each row contains four elements {x,y,z,V}. I have tried to use ListInterpolation, but when I evaluate the interpolating function it happens that it only accepts 2 inputs, but it should accept 3 (x,y,z).

How can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Is your x, y, z data a (full) regular grid, so, excluding the 4th element, V, it looks like, e.g., `Tuples[{Range[0, 1, 0.25], Range[0, 1, 0.2], Range[-1, 1, 0.25]}]`?

Comment: ListInterpolation assumes function values on grid lines. How are your data points structured?

Comment: Hi, the points x,y,z are not equal spaced.  For each points x,y,z i have one scalar V

Comment: Does the scalar field correspond to something physical? If it was like electric potential or charge you could assume a spherical 1/r (or 1/r^2 for charge) falloff and do weighted sums over the grid.

Comment: For a unstructured grid try `Interpolation [{{{x1,y1,z1},V1},{{x2,y2,z2},V2},...},InterpolationOrder->1]`